# Ehcache Deadlock in ehcache 2.9.0

Tags: java, ehcache

We are having app using ehcache 2.9.0. Lately we have observed deadlocks related to ehcache get/put operations weekly once, and once we clear the cache the issue goes away.

we observe the lock on the RandomAccessFile during cache get operation and ReentrantReadWriteLock during put operation.

Request insight from ehcache experts on what could be possible issue ?

PFB the threads from the thread dumps

"HTTP938" #25950 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002614000 nid=0x5a64 waiting on condition [0x00007fcd36965000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005cbbc6768> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.flush(Segment.java:1010)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.flush(DiskStore.java:248)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore$1.evicted(CacheStore.java:99)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore$1.evicted(CacheStore.java:96)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$1.evicted(OnHeapCachingTier.java:86)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.CountBasedBackEnd$1.removed(CountBasedBackEnd.java:103)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.internalReplace(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1346)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.removeAndNotify(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2647)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.CountBasedBackEnd.remove(CountBasedBackEnd.java:115)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.remove(OnHeapCachingTier.java:206)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.put(CacheStore.java:134)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1600)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1526)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.put(EhCacheCache.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:651)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)

"HTTP927" #25855 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fce685c9000 nid=0x4fb6 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fcd359e8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.read(DiskStorageFactory.java:362)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000005cbdfb538> (a java.io.RandomAccessFile)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:864)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.decode(Segment.java:171)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.remove(Segment.java:644)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.remove(DiskStore.java:625)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.remove(CacheStore.java:236)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeInternal(Cache.java:2401)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Cache.java:2162)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1739)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(EhCacheCache.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:432)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)

Thread HTTP762
Owns Monitor Lock on 0x00000005cbdfb538
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:416)
 - locked [0x00000005cbdfb538] (a java.io.RandomAccessFile)
 at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.put(EhCacheCache.java:82)
Thanks,
Nivedita

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but I don't see any deadlock in the thread dump you are showing. Only two threads waiting on different things but not holding of the other thread.

The first tries had to evict a value on a put.

The second thread notice an entry is expired and is removing from the disk storage.

Are you sure it isn't the disk that slows down due to the disk itself or the structure of the data in the cache?

I would also recommend to move to version 2.10.4 which might make the issue disappear.

Comment: There were 39 threads waiting on lock acquired by the Cache put.

Comment: Does the cache put finish at some point? Or it is the same endlessly? Who is locking 0x00000005cbdfb538?

Comment: I find the 0x00000005cbdfb538 is locked by Cache PUt

Comment: Yes, it cache put finishes, but takes too long

Comment: Ok. So I would accuse disk access then.